# Angular + Firestore, How to do this CRUD system?

Tags: database, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, crud

i'm using angular and firestore and I would like to do a CRUD app but i don't understand how I can do this relations between collections.

I have 2 models :

- Library (name, location, description, list of rooms [name])
- Shipping (name, description, list of books [name, author, description])

1 - I would like to add/edit/remove a Library **(I can do this)**

2 - I would like to add a Shipping in which we can have :

1. It's name, description

   - Add a list of books (name, author, description)
   - The Library where the shipping is going

How I can do that with firestore and angularfire2 please ?